# Validating a SAML token at WCF Data Service level

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, saml, adfs2.0

I have a WPF client which request a SAML token from the STS. After receiving the SAML token the WPF client sends the SAML token as part of the request header to the WCF data service. At the WCF data service level the request is interpreted by the Authorisation manager.
I wanted to know is there any way to authenticate this SAML at the service level.(Either by again querying to STS).

Answer (score 0):

http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2010/04/15/integrating-wif-with-wcf-data-services.aspx